# Can blender be used to model an object from accelerometer data?

Tags: 3d-view

If I use the accelerometer in my phone to record data at 100hz, can I then use that data to model how my phone was moving during that time?

Would I also be able to get "kind of" accurate velocity from this as well?

For reference I am part of a dragon boat racing team and I am trying to find a way to appropriately measure the acceleration and velocity of the boat while my team is paddling.

I have successfully gotten the readings in python with pyqt and graphed them in real time (replay from the data) but I cannot see how to get the 3d object simulation like I would like to see in the end...

Comment: You need to solve two problems. The first is reconstructing the motion from the data. The second is visualizing  the motion. To reconstruct the motion, I'd suggest using both accelerometer data and gps data. The two can be combined in various ways. Kalman filters are one way to combine that data. You want to reconstruct the location versus time. Once you have that, you can use the animation nodes plugin to import the location at each frame and set the move an object.

Comment: ok I will look into combiming GPS data. BUT....assuming that I am not so concerned with GPS data and exact vector (I would assume that the boat is traveling in a straight line) Could I get the proper axis (X or Z?) acceleration and subtract the negative acceleration to get an estimated speed or am I missing something in the calculation?

Comment: You should be able to integrate the acceleration to get velocity, then integrate velocity to get the position versus time. Once you have that, you can animate the position versus time.

Comment: hmmm...@EdTate...since the phone GPS can be off by a factor of meters...say I had [1. Fixed starting point, 2. fixed ending point with accurate tripwire timer, 3. accelerometer data] would that be enough to do it as well without gps readings? I am worried that the GPS will be too wildly inaccurate.

Comment: Read the following link: [Visualizing an iOS device in Blender Through Quantum Entanglement](https://medium.com/@JohnCoatesDev/visualizing-an-ios-device-in-blender-through-quantum-entanglement-ba8b6f0b47a5)